# Is this code valid/reasonable to generate a sine wave using an Arduino Uno?

Tags: c, timer, arduino, interrupt

NOTE: I left out the code for the other two phases (V and W), not necessary for the example.

I'm pretty sure, the way I'm handling the "on" and "off" times like this is not an efficient way to do it.

I want to achieve an "on" and "off" pulsation using a look up table. The timer should be compared with the current selected value of the table and switches the output if the value is passed.

Problem: I think I handle the timer "wrong". I'm not getting the right amount of pulses (my understanding is, that I should get as many pulses as the values inside of the array, in this case 300+). Looking on an oscilloscope I noticed, that there are only a few pulses.

Would I be better using the "output compare register"?

What other tips/ideas do you have?

```c
bool posTOneg = true;               // Variable for the change from positive to negative. 'true' in the beginning.

///// CONFIGURATION OF THE PINS /////

int igbt_high_u = 11;
int igbt_high_v = 10;
int igbt_high_w = 9;

int igbt_low_u = 6;
int igbt_low_v = 5;
int igbt_low_w = 3;

///// LOOKUP TABLE /////
int UsinPWM[]={1,2,5,7,10,12,15,17,19,22,24,27,30,32,34,37,39,42,
44,47,49,52,54,57,59,61,64,66,69,71,73,76,78,80,83,85,88,90,92,94,97,99,                                      //42 Werte bis hier hin
101,103,106,108,110,113,115,117,119,121,124,126,128,130,132,134,136,138,140,142,144,146,
148,150,152,154,156,158,160,162,164,166,168,169,171,173,175,177,178,180,182,184,185,187,188,190,192,193,      // 90
195,196,198,199,201,202,204,205,207,208,209,211,212,213,215,216,217,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,
228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,237,238,239,240,240,241,242,242,243,243,244,244,245,245,246,246,      // 142
247,247,247,248,248,248,248,249,249,249,249,249,250,250,250,250,249,249,249,249,249,248,
248,248,248,247,247,247,246,246,245,245,244,244,243,243,242,242,241,240,240,239,238,237,237,236,235,234,      // 190
233,232,231,230,229,228,227,226,225,224,223,222,221,220,219,217,216,215,213,212,211,209,208,207,205,204,
202,201,199,198,196,195,193,192,190,188,187,185,184,182,180,178,177,175,173,171,169,168,166,164,162,160,      // 242
158,156,154,152,150,148,146,144,142,140,138,136,134,132,130,128,126,124,121,119,117,115,113,110,108,106,
103,101,99,97,94,92,90,88,85,83,80,78,76,73,71,69,66,64,61,59,57,54,52,49,47,44,42,39,37,34,32,30,            // 300
27,24,22,19,17,15,12,10,7,5,2,1};                                                                             // 312

///// SIZE OF THE ARRAY /////
int sizeU = sizeof(UsinPWM)/sizeof(int);      // Variable for PWM array (size)
///// OFFSET 120 GRAD /////
int indexU = 0;              // zaehlervariable

///// FUNCTION FOR THE PHASE U (POS AND NEG HALF-CYCLE) /////
void posHalbU (int i)
{
  if(TCNT0 < UsinPWM[i])                              // Compare timer with the current value of the look up table
  {
    digitalWrite(igbt_low_v, HIGH);                   // Triggering hardware
    digitalWrite(igbt_low_w, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(igbt_high_u, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(igbt_high_u, LOW);
    digitalWrite(igbt_low_v, LOW);
    digitalWrite(igbt_low_w, LOW);
  }
}

void negHalbU(int i)
{
  if(TCNT0 < UsinPWM[i])
  {
    digitalWrite(igbt_high_v, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(igbt_high_w, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(igbt_low_u, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(igbt_high_v, LOW);
    digitalWrite(igbt_high_w, LOW);
    digitalWrite(igbt_low_u, LOW);
  }
}


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  ///// CONFIGURE PWM /////
  pinMode(igbt_high_u, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(igbt_high_v, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(igbt_high_w, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(igbt_low_u, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(igbt_low_v, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(igbt_low_w, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  ///// CALL PHASE U  /////
  if(posTOneg)
  {
    posHalbU(indexU);
  }
  else
  {
    negHalbU(indexU);
  }


  indexU = indexU + 1;

  if(indexU == sizeU)
  {
    indexU = 0;                             // Reset of the counter variable
    posTOneg = !posTOneg;                   // Negate the boolean value. Swapping between pos and neg all the time
  }
}
```

Below is the result I am generating. About 20 impulses are created, and these are periodically created.

[image]

Comment: My gut reaction would be to use the sin function and output a scaled value it on an analog pin.  What do you intend to use this for?

Comment: I don't see any timer initialization code.

Comment: @EvilTeach i trigger 6 switches and get therefore a current flow. by the size of the impulses i get a sine wave. <br> 
https://imgur.com/a/ppSZmgN this image shows what i need. i want to generate the blue curves and the way the hardware is configurated is going to give me the red sine wave

Comment: @Eugene Sh: [Timer0 is used by the Arduino functions delay(), millis(), and micros()](https://oscarliang.com/arduino-timer-and-interrupt-tutorial/), and it may already be set up.

Comment: As a first pass, it seems the behaviour is dependent on how fast the main loop runs. Am I wrong? Or is it some kind of modulation? Also, digitalWrite() is very slow compared to a direct digital port output register write. And there are 3*312 = 936 calls to digitalWrite() per cycle.

Comment: Try to make a small test program with loop() containing only digitalWrite(.., LOW); and digitalWrite(.., HIGH); and measure the actual timing on the oscilloscope to get an idea of the actual timing.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for loop` to automatically index through the sine array. Write the data using analogWrite() to a PWM pin at a dedicated time interval. The time interval x array size = sine period.

The output will look terrible ... just a rapidly varying **PWM** signal stretching 0-5  V. After filtering appropriately, a Sine wave will magically appear.

Comment: i dont think that this answer is solving what i m looking for. I may expressed myself wrong. i dont want to have an analog sine wave directly at the pin, i want to activate the switches (igbt_xxx) so that in the end i get a sine wave. 
the switches should rapidly change from high to low while the width of the impulses vary.